# AngularJS button with external link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I assign an external link to a button in Angular?

I should point a button to the "/auth/signout" url, which is outside of Angular.

With links, this works:

```
<a href="/auth/signout"></a>
```

With buttons I tried

```
<button ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
```

and put

```
.controller('notification', ['$scope','$location',function($scope, $location){
    $scope.logout = function() {
        $location.url( '/auth/signout' );
    };
}])
```

in the controller, but nothing happens, probably redirects me to the root of the angular app `.otherwise('/')`.

Also tried `location.href( '/auth/signout' )`, it throws a TypeError: string is not a function.

I could do something like

```
<a href="/auth/signout"><button>Logout</button></a>
```

but it seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Why is that hacky? It is normal behavior to nest the button inside an `a` tag (if you don't need any javascript logic).

Comment: I always thought it was bad practice because of IE compatibility issues. Normally I used jQuery to handle button clicks, but now I try to be good and do everything the proper Angular way :)

Comment: If you use boostrap framework, you can use `<a href="" class="btn"></a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good old simple `window.location = '/auth/signout';` should work just fine.

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: do i have to inject anything to the controller to make this work?

Comment: I updated my question with the whole controller to give it more context

Comment: Actually this works too, I made a mistake and tried window.location( '/auth/signout' ); Sorry, I was too tired.

Comment: No worries. No injections needed unless you plan to use Angular's `$window` instead (probably no need to).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = '/auth/signout';
```

Comment: Sorry Shomz's answer works just as fine, only I made a mistake with it. He was the first with a correct answer so I think the fair thing to do is to accept his answer.